# Create script with custom template

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make the following as the default template of my new C# scripts added in Unity Editor.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public class ScriptName: MonoBehaviour
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>

    #region Fields
    #endregion

    #region MonoBehaviour Messages

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    #endregion

    }
}
```

The ProjectName is a constant for all scripts, while ScriptName is defined on script asset creation.

I tried using UnityEditor documentation and checked this question "[Unity Add Default Namespace to Script Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461801/unity-add-default-namespace-to-script-template)" but couldn't implement the above template

Comment: `but couldn't implement the above template` - why not? Any errors/ unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I checked that but there's no problem.

Check This Point

1. Is AddNameSpace class in the Assets/Editor in project?
2. If you develop CS, modify 81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs in Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates